# Hash small strings into numbers only

Tags: node.js, string, hash, primary-key

My primary key 'is' a string - therefore I want to hash it so I can use the hashed number instead of a string..

I have in total 800 fixed strings (meaning very few and really really low security risk on hashing) so its very unlikely I'll encounter collisions with a simple hash function/method. I considered md5 but since its going to be the primary key in my sqlite table I want to avoid any strings in it. Do you have anything in mind?

Cheers

Comment: Why do you need to hash your strings? Just make a column for that field and add an index to it. md5 would just return another string.

Comment: You are right indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use something like an auto-increment field but if you want a hash you could try this:

```
const crc32 = require("crc32")
const key = "lskdjfasoif";
const idNum = parseInt(crc32(key),16);
```

Comment: I dont want to trouble more fellow answerers as indeed I'll just make my row_id the primary key and simply search for my string, I guess am both an idiot and broken. Since this answer is correct I'll accept it thank you